# how to interpolate and extrapolate the local volatility surface?

Tags: local-volatility, extrapolation, volatility-interpolation

Local volatility can be computed in terms of call prices using Dupire's formula. Assume we have a rectangle call price surface, let's say $I = [30,60]\times[1 day, 1year]$.

For interpolation, should we interpolate the derivatives of call prices and compute the local volatility instead of directly interpolate the local volatility surface?

For extrapolation, should we assume all the derivatives of the call prices be constant if strike or tenor are outside $I$?